# What's the best way to convert Array to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to convert a string array into an object? Is there any one line ES6 code not foreach function?

Array:

```
["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"]
```

Expected object:

```
{ LastName: true, MiddleName: true, FirstName: true }
```

Comment: There are lots of different ways. Which ones have you attempted? Which ones worked? Which ones didn't work? You should add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know the Object.assign and spread operator staff, they are not the same thing. but I would like to have the shortest way, better using ES6.

Comment: Yet another way: `Object.fromEntries(input.map(x => [x,true]))`.

Comment: [A simple loop?](https://jsfiddle.net/3a80vghm/) `const obj = {}; for (const key of arr) { obj[key] = true };`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Array#Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = ["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"]
const object = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = true
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(object)
```